# What does ON do in QBasic?

Tags: qbasic

I have been working on a project, in which I take an old program and create a new version of it .... The thing is that it is written in Quick Basic and it has a line of code that I don't understand

```
ON FLAG% GOTO 1730, 1900
```

Can anyone tell me what this is ???
By the way I'm working on VisualBasic

Comment: The statement gotos 1730 if Flag is 1 and gotos 1900 if Flag is 2 else neither.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is basically a shorthand syntax for this type of statement:

```
IF FLAG% = 1 THEN GOTO 1730 ELSE IF FLAG% = 2 THEN GOTO 1900
```

See [this article](http://www.atarimagazines.com/compute/issue87/The_Power_Of_ON-GOTO_And_ON-GOSUB.php) for more information.

For more options you would probably turn to a `switch` statement in more modern languages.

Answer (score 4):

This is a more structured example of using GOTO statement:

```
SELECT CASE FLAG%
    CASE 1
        GOTO 1730
    CASE 2
        GOTO 1900
END SELECT
```

Comment: More structured example of using GOTO statement.